# Not receiving response sending XML via TCP/IP using Java

Tags: java, xml, sockets, tcp

I'm new to Java (basically had to learn it on the fly for this project), but I'm trying to send an XML command to a server (a sensor in my lab) to get some data from it. To do this, I've written a Java program and I'm running it from the command line. The connection establishes successfully, and (I think) the message is being successfully sent - however it is getting stuck "Awaiting a Response".

Here's my Java code for a reference. I got most of this from a client/server TCP tutorial, and adjusted the IP, port, and outgoing message accordingly. Again, I'm very new to this, so any help is appreciated.

```html
// Java Socket Example - Client

import java.io.IOException; // Throws exception if there is an issue with input or output
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress; // This class represents an Internet Protocol address
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
* This class implements java socket Client
*/

public class SocketClientExample {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
  // get the localhostIP address, if server is running on some other IP, use that 
  System.out.println("Attempting connection to GE Reuter Stokes");
  InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("10.212.160.4"); // IP GOES HERE
  Socket socket = null; // start out as null, protocal
  ObjectOutputStream oos = null; // This will change, just setting default
  ObjectInputStream ois = null;
  // establish the socket connection to the server
  socket = new Socket("10.212.160.4", 3010); // 9876 is just the port number
  System.out.println("Made it past Socket Initialization");
  // write to socket using ObjectOutputStream
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // new instance of OOS that will write to the socket
  System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server"); 
  // Initializing request string
  String request = new String("0xF00041 " + "<Discovery><CommChannelName>Unknown</CommChannelName></Discovery>");
  // In our version, this is where the XML script would go
  oos.writeObject(request);
  System.out.println("Request was sent. Awaiting response.");
  // read the server response message
  ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  // convert the response into a string
  String message = (String) ois.readObject();
  System.out.println("Message: " + message);
  // close your resources
  ois.close();
  oos.close();
  Thread.sleep(100);
 }
}
```

It's more than likely something with the sensor - but I figured it wouldn't hurt to have a second set of eyes on the code.

Comment: Rule out the server side first. Create a test server for this, output the data it gets and other relevant debug messages. Edit this question with results. Use `ServerSocket` for this. Google up the ServerSocket documentation. After creating a new ServerSocket, accept a connection with `Socket client = server.accept();`, then read in the data from that `client`'s output stream, print it, reply.

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` are not the right kinds of streams to use in this situation, and certainly not the `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods. You should be using `OutputStreamWriter` (with a `BufferedWriter` on top of it) or `DataOutputStream`, and `InputStreamReader` (with a `BufferedReader` on top of it).

Comment: Also, what is the `0xF00041` supposed to represent? You do realize that you are sending it as an 8-character string and not as a 3-4 byte integer, don't you? What is the sensor actually expecting you to send? Can you provide some protocol documentation?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! I will try Output/InputStreamWriter and I'll followup with the results. As for the 0xF00041, that represents the standard header that the manual of the sensor specified as follows:
"The XML text is preceded by a binary 5-byte header consisting of (1) Sync Byte - single byte of 0xF0 (2) Length Word - 4 byte integer (Little Endian) w/ the length of the XML message to follow"
Is it possible to transmit a Little Endian value through a socket? I thought you could only transmit strings. I apologize - I've only been at this for a week.

Comment: @BeccaLynch: Read that description more carefully: "*The XML text is preceded by a **binary 5-byte header** ...*". What did I tell you earlier that you are sending? "*you are sending it as an **8-character string** ...*".  With that information, your code is not even remotely close to being accurate for this protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor expects the XML to be preceded by a **binary 5-byte header**, but you are sending the header as an **8-character hex encoded string** instead.

Also, you are using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`, which are meant for serializing Java objects, but you are not sending/reading Java objects.  So these are the completely wrong stream classes to use.

So, your code is not sending what the sensor is expecting, so it will not receive your request correctly, let alone send a response that you can receive.

Try something more like this instead (assuming the sensor sends back a response in a similar header+XML format as the request):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import jva.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class SocketClientExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Attempting connection to GE Reuter Stokes");

        // establish the socket connection to the server
        // using the local IP address, if server is running on some other IP, use that 
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.212.160.4", 3010);
        System.out.println("Socket Connected");

        // write to socket using OutputStream
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        // Initializing request content
        byte[] request = "<Discovery><CommChannelName>Unknown</CommChannelName></Discovery>".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // DataOutputStream.writeInt() writes in big endian and
        // DataInputStream.readInt() reads in big endian.
        // using a ByteBuffer to handle little endian instead.

        byte[] header = new byte[5];
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(header, 1, 4);
        buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        // Initializing request header
        header[0] = (byte) 0xF0;
        buf.putInt(request.length);

        System.out.println("Sending request to Socket Server"); 

        // Sending request
        dos.write(header);
        dos.write(request);
        dos.flush();

        System.out.println("Request was sent. Awaiting response.");

        // read from socket using InputStream
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

        // Read response header
        dis.readFully(header);
        buf.flip();

        // Read response content
        byte[] response = new byte[buf.getInt()];
        dis.readFully(response);

        // convert the content into a string
        String message = new String(response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);

        // close your resources
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();

        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you!